# I want to combine two 4 stroke engine together for my project . What will be the complexities in it ? Will it work?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, engine-theory, crankshaft, india

Bike engine . Want to add two similar bike engine on a single shaft
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMN5u.jpg)[image]

Comment: What have you considered so far? how will you mount the engines - have you checked that the direction of rotation will match etc

Comment: @SolarMike I will use both the engine s of same motorcycle company , will tune same average and weld the gears of both engine and then connect the engines to the shaft through the chains.

Comment: draw a diagram to show what you mean especially consider the engine orientation.

Comment: Google Hogslayer.

Comment: The orientation of the crankshafts relative to each other is crucial.  You can't just connect them at a random point; the resulting harmonics and vibration might literally rip the engine(s) apart.  That appears to be a single cylinder -- I would suggest the firings be together, or alternating (360 degrees) apart for a four-stroke.  You could make them 90 or 180 if you want your project to act like a Harley Davidson, but a Harley is a perfect example why you shouldn't fire both cylinders without respecting the timing.

Comment: Check out drag bikes : 2 ,3 or more engines coupled together in various fashions...

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](http://petrolheadgarage.com/en/Posts/how-to-join-two-ic-engines/) pretty quickly. It's an entire project about exactly that - how to run 2 IC engines together. There's way too much information for me to even decide what to quote, but it's all about the subject of running 2 engines.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment.